# Send email to Umbraco 4

Tags: umbraco, umbraco4

I helping a client with a Umbraco 4 solution. When they send a email message to some special email addresses Umbraco picks them up and creates news post with the email subject, message and picture. One of the emails are failing. Do any of you now where i need to look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not very specific, this could have been achieved in one of many ways. Umbraco doesn't have anything like that built in, so my guess would be that there's a scheduled task that checks the email account somewhere and creates the posts.

To check if the scheduled task is being run by Umbraco, look in /config/umbracoSettings.config and look for the `<scheduledTasks>` element. If there's something listed there, that might give you a clue of where to look.

If there's nothing there, the task is probably being run from elsewhere (windows task scheduler, or event hooks on the mail server maybe), so you'd have to look there.

You could also check the /config/BaseRestExtensions.config file and see if there are any endpoints listed there that might give you a clue as to where the code that does the page creation might live.